# Python - variable inside for loop disappears outside of loop

Tags: python, for-loop, merge-file

**EDIT: If you have also encountered this issue, there are two possible solutions below.**

I am making a very simple Python script to merge several markdown files together, while preserving all line breaks. The files I want to merge are called `markdown/simple1.md`, `markdown/simple2.md`, and `markdown/simple3.md` (they are placed inside a folder called `markdown/`.

This is the text content of `simple1.md`:

```
Page 1

This is some useless content
```

This is the text content of `simple2.md`:

```
Page 2

This is some useless content
```

This is the text content of `simple3.md`:

```
Page 3

This is some useless content
```

And here is what I have so far:

```py
# Define files I want to merge

filenames = ['markdown/simple1.md', 'markdown/simple2.md', 'markdown/simple3.md']

# Merge markdown files into one big file

merged_filecontent = ""
file = ""

for file in filenames:
  file = open(file).read()
  file += "\n"
  # print(file)
  merged_filecontent = file
  print(merged_filecontent)
```

This works perfectly. However, as soon as I try to call a variable outside of my `for` loop, like this:

```py
# Define files I want to merge

filenames = ['markdown/simple1.md', 'markdown/simple2.md', 'markdown/simple3.md']

# Merge markdown files into one big file

merged_filecontent = ""
file = ""

for file in filenames:
  file = open(file).read()
  file += "\n"
  # print(file)
  merged_filecontent = file
  
# Call variable outside of for loop

print(merged_filecontent)
```

The variable only returns the 3rd markdown file, and doesn't show the merged file.

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: The central problem here is that you need to work through a tutorial on how to work with Python files.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: @Prune Understood. However, I should explain that I had looked extensively through Stack Overflow for the past half-hour, and I had not found a suitable solution to my issue. For this reason, I felt it neccesary to ask this question, and thus allow anyone in the future who has this problem to find a solution with this SO post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually merge the file content with `merged_filecontent += file`

```
# Define files I want to merge

filenames = ['markdown/simple1.md', 'markdown/simple2.md', 'markdown/simple3.md']

# Merge markdown files into one big file

merged_filecontent = ""
file = ""

for file in filenames:
  file = open(file).read()
  file += "\n"
  # print(file)
  merged_filecontent += file
  
# Call variable outside of for loop

print(merged_filecontent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're re-declaring the `file` variable inside the loop. Try:

```
filenames = ['markdown/simple1.md', 'markdown/simple2.md', 'markdown/simple3.md']
merged_filecontent = ""

for file in filenames:
  with open(file) as f:
    merged_filecontent += f.read()+"\n"

print(merged_filecontent)
```